# How to get selected rows in vb6 TDBgrid

Tags: vb6

I'm a beginner in VB6.
I am creating an application that contains a TDBGrid.
My problem is how can i get the row selected in this TDBGrid.

Comment: you mean true db grid?

Comment: Yes, i mean true db grid

Comment: I change the TDBgrid to DataGrid, how can i getthe selected Row from datagrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you have changed to dbgrid then you can do below

```
Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.SelectedRow 

Dim CellValue = row.Cells(1).Text
```